# put() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

This is my code in Views.py

```
class NotificationsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]
    queryset = Notifications.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotificationsSerializer
    filter_fields = ('status','task','survey_type',)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        notifications = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = NotificationsSerializer(notifications, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        notifications = self.get_object(pk)
        notifications.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

When i try to use method PUT i got error `put() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)`. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: how are you using the `PUT` method?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov I'm using angular2

Comment: rename your function from `put` to `update` and see if it works

Comment: @aliva i rename the function and got this error `Method "PUT" not allowed.`

Answer (score 1):

```
def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
```

It takes 3 arguments at the minimum. Like:

```
self.put(request, pk)
```

`self` variable needs to be passed.

Alternatively,

```
put(self, request, pk)
```

Or 4 arguments at the max,

```
self.put(request, pk, format)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you're doing a PUT on the set entry point where the pk isn't defined. Make it optional:

```
def put(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
```

Note that there's no point in using viewset if you're overriding `put`.

Comment: i got this error after change `pk=None`.. `get_object() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: then re-read the first part of my answer. Also note that this is another question.